# NFS only gives user read access

Tags: nfs, home-server, fstab, linux-server

I had NFS set up such that my RasberryPi had its `Documents/` folder stored on my main Ubuntu system and it worked fine. I then made it such that the entire `/home/raspi1` folder (note, not `/home/` itself) was stored on my Ubuntu NFS server. However, now I no longer have write access to those files/folders.

Here is my `exports` file on my Ubuntu server. `192.168.1.109` is the internal ip address of my Raspberry Pi client.

**/etc/exports (server):**

```
/home/USER/Documents/raspi/raspi1 192.168.1.109(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

Here is the fstab file on my Raspberry Pi client. `192.168.1.102` is the internal ip address of my Ubuntu Server.

**/etc/fstab (client):**

```
192.168.1.102:/home/USER/Documents/raspi/raspi1 /home/raspi1 nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,rw,auto,nolock
```

After which, on the server, I issue the command

```
sudo exportfs -a
```

Now, when I log into my Raspberry Pi, and issue the command `ls -l /home/raspi1`, I get the following output

**Output:**

```
total 88
drwxrwxr-x 13 4294967294 4294967294  4096 Oct  2 04:33 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root       root        4096 Oct  2 03:46 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 4294967294 4294967294  3390 Oct  2 04:32 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x  2 4294967294 4294967294  4096 Oct  2 03:44 bin
drwxr-xr-x  3 4294967294 4294967294  4096 Oct  2 03:44 camcv
drwxr-xr-x  3 4294967294 4294967294  4096 Oct  2 03:44 camcv.step4
drwxr-xr-x  3 4294967294 4294967294  4096 Oct  2 03:44 camcv.step5
drwxr-xr-x  3 4294967294 4294967294  4096 Oct  2 03:44 camcv.step5.5
drwxr-xr-x  3 4294967294 4294967294  4096 Oct  2 03:44 camcv.step6
-rw-r--r--  1 4294967294 4294967294   475 Oct  2 04:32 .inputrc
drwxr-xr-x  4 4294967294 4294967294  4096 Oct  2 03:44 magicMirror
drwxr-xr-x  5 4294967294 4294967294  4096 Oct  2 03:44 media
drwxr-xr-x  3 4294967294 4294967294  4096 Oct  2 03:44 motionDetection
-rw-r--r--  1 4294967294 4294967294   675 Oct  2 04:32 .profile
drwx------  2 4294967294 4294967294  4096 Oct  2 04:33 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x 21 4294967294 4294967294  4096 Oct  2 04:34 .vim
-rw-r--r--  1 4294967294 4294967294 21938 Oct  2 04:33 .vimrc
```

Who is user `4294967294` and what has gone wrong here?

**EDIT:** If I try to export and then mount a different folder, lets say `/home/USER/xyz` to `/home/raspi1/xyz`, it works out as expected, with the file/folder owners being `raspi1`.

**EDIT2:** Issuing the below commands on the RaspberryPi client generate different results.

```
showmount -a 192.168.1.102
showmount -e 192.168.1.102
```

**output:**

```
All mount points on 192.168.1.102:
192.168.1.109:/home/USER/xyz

Export list for 192.168.1.102:
/home/USER/xyz              192.168.1.109
/home/USER/Documents/raspi/raspi1 192.168.1.109
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I did not find out what was going on, despite [this insightful answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/98741/files-mounted-over-nfsv4-are-owned-by-4294967294-uids-and-gids-match) over on ServerFault, I did, however, find a work around. Just use NFS3 instead of NSF4. To do so, just add `nfsvers=3` to the `/etc/fstab/` file like so

**/etc/fstab:**

```
192.168.1.102:/home/USER/Documents/raspi/raspi1 /home/raspi1 nfs nfsvers=3,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,rw,auto,nolock
```

This fixed the `UID=4294967294` issue, although it has led to another issue whereby the file is owned by a user other than `raspi1` (user `pi`), see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/543435/who-gets-ownership-of-a-mounted-file-folder-in-nfs).