# Who gets ownership of a mounted file/folder in NFS?

Tags: nfs, mount, file-permissions, ownership

I am stumped with [a problem I raised over on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/653475/nfs-only-gives-user-read-access) and I basically got around it by using NFS version 3. Now, although I no longer have the user `4294967294` problem, now the files I mount are all owned by a user other than that which I want (RaspberryPi's original `pi` instead of the one I created, `raspi1`). Both users have root access, so my question is how are ownerships assigned under NFS? Is there anyway to designate who owns a file or is it based on the mount location?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a `map_static` option which you can use in `/etc/exports` to specify mappings between client and server UIDs/GIDs, but that is deprecated. Turns out, the UID and GIDs **must** be identical on both machines. I find this a little silly, but can easily be achieved through a few commands such as `usermod` and `groupmod`.

Comment: Silly as it may seem to you, NFS was designed primarily as a complement to NIS. In an NIS domain, all users authenticate to the same directory, regardless of the client, and thus all have consistent UID's between systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`anonuid=1234,anongid=1234`

in your `/etc/exports`, to define the user/group under which all files and folders will get written onto your NFS destination.

Comment: Thank you. Could you maybe provide a sample line illustrating how to add those flags.